# Does a monk with Extra Attack trigger Martial Arts if only one attack is unarmed?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

So, I've created a "sumo" monk who has the [Grappler](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/grappler) feat, and is now level 5 and has the [Extra Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/monk#ExtraAttack) class feature. Since I'd like to use one of these attacks to [grapple](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) the target, can I use my other attack to punch the grappled target, then use [Martial Arts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/monk#MartialArts) to punch him again?

[Grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Grappling):

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the Attack action to make a special melee attack, a grapple. **If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them**.

[Martial Arts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/monk#MartialArts):

> **When you use the Attack action with an unarmed strike or a monk weapon** on your turn, you can make one unarmed strike as a bonus action.

Specifically, the wording of Martial Arts doesn't really take Extra Attack into account, since you could make one of those attacks with a monk weapon and or unarmed strike, then draw a longsword and make the other attack with that (or in my case, grapple). I know that Martial Arts does also say "while you are unarmed or wielding only monk weapons", which the longsword example would contradict, but my grapple example doesn't, since I'm still not wielding any weapons or wearing armour/shield.

So my question is **Is Martial Arts triggered if only one of the two attacks is an unarmed strike or monk weapon attack (with the other being a grapple), or do both of them have to be unarmed strikes/monk weapon attacks**?

Comment: +1 since I love when questions make you question whether the way you've been playing the game has been wrong all along. I've done this exact thing like 20 times (with shove more often than grapple because we have a wizard obsessed with terrain modification) and just assumed it worked that way without even checking if it required all attacks as US.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Yes, yes you can!

The [Monk Martial Arts requirement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/classes#Monk) states (emphasis mine):

> **When you use the Attack action with an unarmed strike or a monk weapon** on your turn, you can make one unarmed strike as a bonus action.

And Extra Attack stipulates:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

Nothing in the language of either requires ALL attacks to be made with unarmed strikes. It only requires that you use the Attack action (you did) with an unarmed strike (you did with one of your attacks) in order to be able to use a bonus action unarmed strike.

### Is grapple an unarmed strike?

[Grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#ActionsinCombat) would *not* be considered an unarmed as it is not listed under the Unarmed Strikes but in it's own section that states (emphasis mine):

> you can use the Attack action to make a special melee attack

Grappling (while still unarmed) is not part of the options for Unarmed Strikes as it is distinctly a Special Melee Attack.

This is also confirmed by [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/708007593701089280):

> The shove and grapple options don't involve an attack with a weapon or an unarmed strike, so no

As long as you use your Extra Attack for an unarmed strike, you will be able to use your Martial Arts for a Bonus Action Unarmed Strike.

Comment: Oh shoot. Mobile made my answer an edit. I rolled it back. Sorry

Comment: You can use [this](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/03/09/does-the-special-shove-prone-attack-count-as-an-unarmed-strike/) and [this](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/03/31/does-shove-qualify-you-to-use-the-bonus-attack-in-two-weapon-fighting-or-martial-arts/) if you wanted some explicit ruling on grapple/shove not being unarmed (also the first one is so cl0se to answering this question but not quite).

Comment: The ambiguity in language choice in this system sometimes baffles me.

Comment: There is also an instance in the Polearm Master feat that says (emphasis mine) "When you take the Attack action and attack with **only**
a glaive, halberd, or quarterstaff, you can use a bonus
action to make a melee attack with the opposite end of
the weapon." - PHB 168

Comment: @KakunaRattata I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @NautArch I mean that the wording for martial arts does not specify that you need to *only* attack with an unarmed strike or monk weapon. Whereas here in PAM they do specify.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes.

#### As long as one of your attacks during your Attack Action is an unarmed strike, you may use Martial Arts to make one extra unarmed strike as a Bonus Action.

You may use different weapons for different attacks as part of the same Attack Action.  Although a very strict reading of this text may seem like you should have to use unarmed strike for all your attacks, I don't think that is how the rule was intended.  For my interpretation, I am satisfied with any of the attacks triggering the availability of Martial Arts (since that would be a case of using your Attack Action to make an unarmed strike or attack with a monk weapon, regardless of what the other attack was used for).

While there aren't any restrictions on what the other extra attack can be, note that ***Monks cannot use Martial Arts while wielding non-monk weapons***.  This is not an opening for Monks to use heavy/two-handed weapons along with unarmed strikes.  When holding a Halberd for instance, the Monk's unarmed strike would use Strength for the attack, deal 1+Str bludgeoning damage, and would not allow for using a bonus action to make an extra unarmed strike.  (You would however still benefit from Unarmored Defense.)

Comment: Breaking down the logic chain would help this.

Comment: I am failing to find any tweets, errata, or sage advice to support or refute this, but still looking.

Comment: Per the [Sage Advice Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf): "**When you use Extra Attack, do you have to use the same  weapon for all the attacks?** Extra Attack imposes no limitation on what you use for the attacks. You can use regular  weapons, improvised weapons, unarmed strikes, or a combination of these options for the attacks." Also supported by Crawford's tweets [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/30/if-wielding-a-sword-in-each-hand-can-you-decide-what-to-main-action-attack/) and [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/12/05/extra-attack/).

Comment: So that part is certainly allowed. The only question is whether Martial Arts requires that all attacks in the Attack action (if there are multiple) meet the criteria specified in the Martial Arts feature. As worded, I don't think anything requires that additional attacks (that are part of the Attack action) meet the criteria, simply that one of the attacks that is part of the Attack action meet it. ...But that raised another question: can monks use a non-"monk weapon"/unarmed strike as one of those multiple attacks and still gain the benefit of Martial Arts?

Comment: @V2Blast - answered this with an edit (new paragraph).

Comment: @NickBrown: Good point, I skimmed over this part at the start of the Martial Arts feature: "You gain the following benefits while you are unarmed or wielding only monk weapons and you aren't wearing armor or wielding a shield." I missed it because they repeatedly mention "unarmed strikes and monk weapons" in every bullet point of Martial Arts as well as in the introductory portion.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

I would argue you, in the most literal sense, "used the Attack action with an unarmed strike and a special melee attack (grapple)". Since this includes using the Attack action with an unarmed strike, you will have satisfied the requirement for the Martial Arts feature.

> **When you use the Attack action with an unarmed strike** ... you can make one unarmed strike as a bonus action.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes you can**

Note that Grappling is also an Attack Action:

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, **you can use the Attack action** to make a special melee attack, a grapple. If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.

The ruling in this case is if you are considered Grappling with an unarmed strike or a monk weapon (Definitely not unarmed strike). While **not RAW**, unless you can convince your DM you are grappling the target with your monk weapon, i would let the monk use Martial Arts with a single Grapple.

> You don't grapple with a weapon - you grapple with "Using at least one free hand". A DM can house-rule anything, but this changes the fundamental grappling requirements.

– NautArch

*Back to your question!*

For the extra attack it's not specified for one or two attacks. So the trigger condition is either met or not.

> "Did you attack with an unarmed strike or monk weapon?"
>
> "Yes."
>
> "You can use Martial Arts."

Comment: Grappling is not an Unarmed Strike, though. If the character only had one Attack and did a grapple, they wouldn't qualify for the Martial Arts Bonus Action.

Comment: @NautArch is this better?

Comment: You don't grapple with a weapon - you grapple with "Using at least one free hand". A DM can house-rule anything, but this changes the fundamental grappling requirements.